# Farthest celestial body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solar-system

Pluto and Neptune Which from the two is farthest  **celestial** body from earth ? I googled about their distance from sun and found that sometimes Neptune is far from sun and sometimes Pluto , before 1999 Neptune was the farthest planet but after 1999 Pluto is the farthest planet for next 238 years . In my exam this question was asked as a multiple choice question and I have to choose from either of the two options ( Pluto or Neptune ) Which one will be correct option to choose?

Comment: (Map of Pluto and Neptune Orbits)[https://www.google.ie/search?q=pluto+and+neptune+map+oforbit&oq=pluto+and+neptune+map+oforbit&aqs=chrome..69i57.18206j0j4&client=ms-android-htc-rev&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=WYiheMVfFWgpxM%3A&xxri=10].  Also https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/exploring-the-planets/online/solar-system/pluto/orbit.cfm

Comment: It's pretty clear from your query that you know the answer from your own research, so why are you questioning that research?

Comment: @KyleKanos I am not questioning the research I am just asking "what answer should I mark in the exam ?"  Please read the last part of the question's body which I posted.

Comment: Your research clearly says what the answer should be, so you seem to be questioning your research (by asking what you should mark off, if you want to be more specific)

Comment: Note that "distance from the Sun" and "distance from Earth" are two different things. The proper calculation would have to include a time stamp, given that (as you observed) the answer changes with time.

Answer (score 2):

Same question was asked on a NASA site with the same question: [Is Pluto or Neptune farthest from the Sun?](https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/questions/question5.html), a key point is that Pluto

> "crosses" inside of Neptune's orbit for 20 years out of every 248 years.

The last interval was from 1979-1999, as can be seen in the orbital diagram below:

[image]

*Image source: [University of Oregon](http://pages.uoregon.edu/jimbrau/astr121/Notes/Chapter13.html)*

This is due to Pluto's elliptical orbit, the orbital variation is shown in the diagram below (from the NASA page):

[image]

(so, you can see that Pluto won't collide with Neptune).

You should be able to answer your question from this information (and the links)

Comment: I too read this article but still couldn't clear my doubt whether I should choose Pluto or Neptune as my answer in exam .

Comment: Think of it this way, what years was Neptune the farthest? What year is it now?

Comment: What's up, Doc? *::munches on carrot::* In your second image, is the abscissa the total/radial distance from the Sun? Or is it simply the magnitude of the component of the radial distance that lies in the ecliptic plane? If the former, then Pluto is clearly closer than Neptune at times. If the latter, then it is a close call. $29AU$ out and $9AU$ up is farther away than Neptune's $30AU$ out.